# how to rename a dataframe column which is a digit like name?

Tags: python, pandas, dummy-variable

I have a dataframe column contains 10 different digits. Through `pd.get_dummies` I've got 10 new columns which column names are numbers. Then I want to rename these number named columns by `df = df.rename(columns={'0':'topic0'})` but failed. How can I rename these columns' name from numbers to strings?

Comment: `df.rename(columns={0: 'topic0'}, inplace=True)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':[1,5,7,8,3,6,5,8,9,10]})

df1 = pd.get_dummies(df['col']).add_prefix('topic')
print (df1)
   topic1  topic3  topic5  topic6  topic7  topic8  topic9  topic10
0       1       0       0       0       0       0       0        0
1       0       0       1       0       0       0       0        0
2       0       0       0       0       1       0       0        0
3       0       0       0       0       0       1       0        0
4       0       1       0       0       0       0       0        0
5       0       0       0       1       0       0       0        0
6       0       0       1       0       0       0       0        0
7       0       0       0       0       0       1       0        0
8       0       0       0       0       0       0       1        0
9       0       0       0       0       0       0       0        1
```

Answer (score 0):

With the example dataframe you can do:

```
d = {0: [1, 2], 1: [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

You can do for example:

```
df.rename(index=str, columns={0: "a", 1: "c"})
```

And then use this method to rename the other columns.

Compactly:

```
for x in range(3):
    df.rename(index=str, columns={x: "topic"+str(x)})
```

Comment: TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: Recommend jezrael's solution then.